# VirtualBox - Can I use a non supported HW which is not supported by my host OS in my guest OS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am trying to use an external wireless antenna (Alfa Network AWUS036H) with a Linux VirtualBox virtual machine but it doesn't work.

I can see the antenna by clicking on Devices > USB but when I try to attach it to virtual machine, nothing happens.

My host is running OSX El Capitan which doesn't support this HW.

Is it possible to use a HW which is not supported by the host OS at all?

Edited:

5 minutes later I got this error:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Comment: You should still be able to passthrough the device to the guest even if your host does not support it. It's just Linux may not support it either (you can check with `lsusb -t` to see whether a driver is loaded for it).